# Python regex to match and remove the indels in pileup format

Tags: python, regex

My question is similar to the following post but I need this python:

[Mpileup regex command to remove indels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206608/mpileup-regex-command-to-remove-indels#new-answer)

INPUT:
    chr8    30  T   6   ...,$.$.$A,..A...,,,.,,...+5AGGC...-8GTCGG......,a,^F,^].^F,

I want to remove the indels that may be similar to `+5AGGC` and `-8GTCGG`

OUTPUT:
    chr8    30  T   6   ...,$.$.$A,..A...,,,....,,.........,a,^F,^].^F,

I tried with the following regex but doesnt work, pls help

```
= re.sub(" [+]?([0-9]+)([ACGTNacgtn]+)", "", seq)

= re.sub("-\d+[ACGT]+", "", seq)
```

Comment: Regex questions like this need a sample input and output http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: Sorry about that updated now

Answer (score 1):

> This one worked finally
>
> sequence = re.sub("+\d+[ACGT]+", "", sequence)

Except of course, it's wrong.  Consider:

```
.....+5AGGCTA.....
```

The `[ACGT]+` is ***greedy*** will eat ***all*** the bases, not just the five that the pileup notation says are indels.  You can verify this if you have a quality scores string as the lengths of the two strings won't agree after removing indels and other artifacts.  Conceptually, the pattern we want is:

```
r"[+-](\d+)[ACTG]{\1}"
```

But the regex syntax doesn't allow us to put variables in the general form of the repetition operator, i.e. `{5}` is fine but not the back reference `{\1}`.

There are several ways to go about this, mostly involving two steps: first, match the initial part through the count; second, use that count to finish the job.  Here's an example:

```
import re

pileup = '...,$.$.$A,..A...,,,.,,...+5AGGCTA..-8GTCGGAAAT......,a,^F,^].^F,'

while True:
    match = re.search(r"[+-](\d+)", pileup)

    if match is None:
        break

    pileup = pileup[:match.start()] + pileup[match.end() + int(match.group(1)):]

print(pileup)
```

Match the sign and the count, extract the count.  Then cut the match itself plus count characters out of the string.  Repeat until you don't find any more indels.

**OUTPUT**

```
...,$.$.$A,..A...,,,.,,...A..T......,a,^F,^].^F,
```

Another approach is to use the results of the first pattern match to dynamically create a second pattern that you can pass to `re.sub()` to remove each indel in turn.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked finally

sequence = re.sub("+\d+[ACGT]+", "", sequence)

sequence = re.sub("-\d+[ACGT]+", "", sequence)

Might be helpful for someone who is looking for regex to remove indels from their pileup file.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `re.compile('[-+]\d+[ACGTacgtNn]+')` to replace all the indels:

```
>>> import re
>>> REOBJ_RM_INDEL = re.compile('[-+]\d+[ACGTacgtNn]+')
>>> bases="...,$.$.$A,..A...,,,.,,...+4AGGC...-5GTCGG......,a,^F,^].^F,"
>>> REOBJ_RM_INDEL.sub('', bases)
... ...,$.$.$A,..A...,,,.,,............,a,^F,^].^F,
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Consider `bases = 'A+4AGGCA'`, the result should be `'AA'` but instead you get `'A'`